# Pygame have cubes move from top to bottom of screen slowly

Tags: python, pygame

I am making my first pygame game which is why i have asked so many questions since i am learning about it. I am trying to make cubes fall from the sky slowly and when they hit the bottom of the screen they go back to above the screen and start falling again. My code is not produce any errors but also not working properly because the cubes are not appearing at all. Here is my code hope you can help thanks!:

```
import pygame
import sys
from random import randint

x = 250
y = 30

import os

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS"] = "%d,%d" % (x, y)

width = 1024
height = 768

icon1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santa-claus.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon1)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gift Catcher")
background_image = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/wintervillage.png")

sprite1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santabag2.png")
rect = sprite1.get_rect()
speed = 2.5
# 442 or 467
rect.x = 442

icon2 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/present1.png")
icon3 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/present2.png")
icon4 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/present3.png")
icon5 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/present4.png")

cubes = [[
    randint(1, 1000),  # X coordinate
    randint(-300, 100)]  # Y coordinate, -Y is above screen  (top of screen is zero)
    for x in range(7)]  # 20 cubes

for cb in cubes:
    cb[1] += 10  # cube moves down 2 pixels
    screen.blit(icon2, cb)  # draw cube
    if cb[1] > 800:  # if cube passed bottom of screen
        cb[1] = -100  # move to above screen
        cb[0] = randint(1, 1000)  # random X position

for cb in cubes:
    cb[1] += 10  # cube moves down 2 pixels
    screen.blit(icon3, cb)  # draw cube
    if cb[1] > 800:  # if cube passed bottom of screen
        cb[1] = -100  # move to above screen
        cb[0] = randint(1, 1000)  # random X position

for cb in cubes:
    cb[1] += 10  # cube moves down 2 pixels
    screen.blit(icon4, cb)  # draw cube
    if cb[1] > 800:  # if cube passed bottom of screen
        cb[1] = -100  # move to above screen
        cb[0] = randint(1, 1000)  # random X position

for cb in cubes:
    cb[1] += 10  # cube moves down 2 pixels
    screen.blit(icon5, cb)  # draw cube
    if cb[1] > 800:  # if cube passed bottom of screen
        cb[1] = -100  # move to above screen
        cb[0] = randint(1, 1000)  # random X position

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    rect.y = 600

    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You must draw the cubes in the application loop after `screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))` but before `pygame.display.flip()`

Comment: i tried that and now I can see the cubes but they are flying all over the place and not going down

Comment: nevermind i got it working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must draw the cubes in the application loop after `screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))` but before `pygame.display.flip()`. For example:

```py
running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    for cb in cubes:
        screen.blit(icon5, cb)

    screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```